# PHP meeting search conditions

Tags: php, search, if-statement, conditional-statements

i'm at PHP entry level so i don't really understand how to do it.

This website is like a short story submission page

First i have the search.php The page will allows users to search for story records using multiple conditions such as what the content contains so i have this:
storySearch.php

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
       <td>Include:
          <select name="optionContent">
             <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
             <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
       </td>
       <td>Story content contains: <input type="text" name="contains" /></td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
       <td>Include:
          <select name="optionNum">
             <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
             <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
       </td>
       <td> Number of words:<b> from </b> <input type="text" name="minWord" style="width: 25px;"><b> from </b>
          <input type="text" name="maxWord" style="width: 25px;" />
       </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type='submit' value='Submit' />
```

and ....submit i cut out some codes

The problem is in the page it is posted to, doStorySearch.php

If each include option is Yes, i need to include it as a search condition for my database.
if and else statement seem to be the way but i have no idea how. this is what i got for my doStorySearch.php

```
   <?php
        $checkContent = $_POST['optionContent'];
        $checkNum = $_POST['optionNum'];
        if ($checkContent == 'yes') {
            $content = $_POST['contains'];
            echo $content;
        }
        else if( $checkNum == 'Yes') {
            $NumS = $_POST['minWord'];
            $NumE = $_POST['maxWord'];
            echo $NumS."And". $NumE;
        }
```

I don't understand how to do after this part.whether ifelse or else?. Any help will be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There truly are a hundred ways you could do it.

I'd work with booleans, even if there's still some repetition, it avoids most of it:

```
$checkContent = $_POST['optionContent'] == 'yes';
$checkNum     = $_POST['optionNum'] == 'yes';

if ($checkContent && $checkNum) {
    // Do both
    }
else if ($checkContent) {
    // only content
    }
else if ($checkNum) {
    // only numbers
    }
else {
    // error checking
    }
```

Is this clear enough ? Booleans may not be intuitive at first, but once understood, they really make your code clear and readable.

If you plan using SQL, remember to sanitize your inputs.